# Find 2 closest previous values and 2 closest next values in a sorted array list

Tags: java, search, arraylist, binary-search

This is a modified binary search that returns the closest element from a sorted array list to the value given. How can I tweak it so that it can return the 2 closest previous and 2 closest next elements?

```
private static Long search(long value, ArrayList<Long> a) {

    if(value < a.get(0)) {
        return a.get(0);
    }
    if(value > a.get(a.size()-1)) {
        return a.get(a.size()-1);
    }

    int lo = 0;
    int hi = a.size() - 1;

    while (lo <= hi) {
        int mid = (hi + lo) / 2;
        if (value < a.get(mid)) {
            hi = mid - 1;
        } else if (value > a.get(mid)) {
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else {
            return a.get(mid);
        }
    }
    return (a.get(lo) - value) < (value - a.get(hi)) ? a.get(lo) : a.get(hi);
}
```

For example lets consider my array list is consisted of these elements:

[101, 201, 301, 401, 501, 601, 701, 801, 901, 1001]

I have been given the value of 730. I want the search to return an array of 4 elements consisted of 601, 701 as the previous values and 801 and 901 as the next values.

Comment: Will there always be two previous and two next values?  What should the output be if `value` is already in the `List`?

Comment: I wrote an answer below - let me know if it helps.

Comment: The value being already in the list is really rare with my actual dataset. However if that were to happen it should ignore the value and return the 2 previous and 2 next values. For my example if I was given the value 501 I want the list to return [301, 401, 601, 701].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a quite straightforward approach this code adds elements to the result list depending on difference between `lo`, `hi` and `mid` values.

In the edge cases the number of elements returned can be less than 4. For example, if there are no elements to the left or to the right (because of the list boundaries), the returned list size can be 2 or 3 depending on the positions of the closest values.

If it's what you want, then here is the code:

```
private static List<Long> search(long value, List<Long> a) {
    if (a.size() < 3) return new ArrayList<>(a);
    List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (value < a.get(0)) {
        result.add(a.get(0));
        result.add(a.get(1));
        return result;
    }
    if (value > a.get(a.size() - 1)) {
        result.add(a.get(a.size() - 2));
        result.add(a.get(a.size() - 1));
        return result;
    }

    int lo = 0;
    int hi = a.size() - 1;
    int match = -1;

    while (lo <= hi) {
        int mid = (hi + lo) / 2;
        if (value < a.get(mid)) {
            hi = mid - 1;
        } else if (value > a.get(mid)) {
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else {
            match = mid;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (match >= 0) {
        if (match > 1) result.add(a.get(match - 2));
        if (match > 0) result.add(a.get(match - 1));
        if (match < a.size() - 1) result.add(a.get(match + 1));
        if (match < a.size() - 2) result.add(a.get(match + 2));
    } else if (a.get(lo) < value) {
        result.add(a.get(hi));
        result.add(a.get(lo));
        if (lo < a.size() - 1) result.add(a.get(lo + 1));
        if (lo < a.size() - 2) result.add(a.get(lo + 2));
    } else if (a.get(hi) > value) {
        if (hi > 1) result.add(a.get(hi - 2));
        if (hi > 0) result.add(a.get(hi - 1));
        result.add(a.get(hi));
        result.add(a.get(lo));
    } else {
        if (hi > 0) result.add(a.get(hi - 1));
        result.add(a.get(hi));
        result.add(a.get(lo));
        if (lo < a.size() - 1) result.add(a.get(lo + 1));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @thelaw edited according to your comment to ignore the exact match

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @thelaw I was glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to extend your original code to accommodate returning a list of four values, and it's relatively easy:

```
    private static List<Long> search(long value, ArrayList<Long> a) {

    List<Long> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (null == a) {
        return null;
    }
    if (a.isEmpty()) {
        return a;
    }
    if (a.size()==1) {
        return a;
    }
    if(value < a.get(0)) {
        returnList.add(a.get(0));
        returnList.add(a.get(1));
        return returnList;
    }
    if(value > a.get(a.size()-1)) {
        returnList.add(a.get(a.size()-1));
        returnList.add(a.get(a.size()-2));
        return returnList;
    }

    int lo = 0;
    int hi = a.size() - 1;

    while (lo <= hi) {
        int mid = (hi + lo) / 2;
        if (value < a.get(mid)) {
            hi = mid - 1;
        } else if (value > a.get(mid)) {
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else {
            if (mid>1) returnList.add(a.get(mid-2));
            if (mid>0) returnList.add(a.get(mid-1));
            if (mid<=a.size()-1) returnList.add(a.get(mid+1));
            if (mid<=a.size()-2) returnList.add(a.get(mid+2));
            return returnList;
        }
    }
    if ((a.get(lo) - value) < (value - a.get(hi))) {
        if (lo > 0) returnList.add(a.get(lo-1));
        returnList.add(a.get(lo));
        if (lo<=a.size()-1) returnList.add(a.get(lo+1));
        if (lo<=a.size()-2) returnList.add(a.get(lo+2)); 
    } else {
        if (lo > 1) returnList.add(a.get(hi-2));
        if (lo > 0) returnList.add(a.get(hi-1));
         ReturnList.add(a.get(hi));
        if (hi<=a.size()-1) returnList.add(a.get(hi+1));
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

However, if we're extending the code, it could be the best time to do some small refactoring, to make it more readable.

```
    private static List<Long> addNumbersAroundIndex (int index, Long searchedNum, int numOfElements, List<Long> list) {
    List<Long> returnList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    int before = numOfElements/2;
    int after = numOfElements - before;

    if (list.get(index)>searchedNum) {
        after --;

    } else if(list.get(index)<searchedNum) {

        before--;
    }
    for (int i=before; i>0; i--) {

        if (index>i+1) returnList.add(list.get(index-i));
    }
    if (!list.get(index).equals(searchedNum)) {
        returnList.add(list.get(index));
    }
    for (int i=1; i< after+1; i++) {

        if (index+i<=list.size()-1) returnList.add(list.get(index+i));
    }
    return returnList;
}

private static List<Long> search(long value, int numOfElements, ArrayList<Long> a) {

    if (null == a) {
        return null;
    }
    if (a.isEmpty()) {
        return a;
    }
    if (a.size()==1) {
        return a;
    }
    if(value < a.get(0)) {
        return addNumbersAroundIndex(0, value, numOfElements,a);
    }
    if(value > a.get(a.size()-1)) {
        return addNumbersAroundIndex(a.size()-1, value,numOfElements,a);
    }

    int lo = 0;
    int hi = a.size() - 1;

    while (lo <= hi) {
        int mid = (hi + lo) / 2;
        if (value < a.get(mid)) {
            hi = mid - 1;
        } else if (value > a.get(mid)) {
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else {
            return addNumbersAroundIndex(mid,value,numOfElements,a);
        }
    }
    if ((a.get(lo) - value) < (value - a.get(hi))) {
        return addNumbersAroundIndex(lo,value,numOfElements,a);
    } else {
        return addNumbersAroundIndex(hi,value,numOfElements,a);
    }
}
```

Testing it with a few of your original list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(101l, 201l, 301l, 401l, 501l, 601l, 701l, 801l, 901l, 1001l));
    System.out.println(search(1020l,5,list));

}

[801, 901, 1001]

System.out.println(search(730l,4,list));

[601, 701, 801, 901]

System.out.println(search(601l,5,list));

[401, 501, 701, 801, 901]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is really helpful. However perhaps I didn't make it clear in my question that I always want it to return 2 previous values and 2 next values. For example if in your code I put as input 700 the list returns [601, 701, 801, 901]. I want it to return [501, 601, 701, 801]. 501 and 601 are the previous values and 701 and 801 are the next values. Also check the comments in my question regarding the case if value is already in the List.

Comment: @thelaw I fixed it to your specifications. It works as you expect it.